# Inequality between two sums

Tags: inequality, summation, normed-spaces, holder-inequality

As part of a research problem I am working on, I need to show the following inequality. Let $x=(x_1,\dots,x_K)$ with $x_i > 0$ for all $i$. Then, I wish to show that 
$$ \frac{1}{K^2}\sum_{i=1}^K x_i \geq K \left(\sum_{i=1}^K x_i^{-1/2}\right)^{-2}.$$
For $K=2$ this is easy to show with simple algebra, but for the general case I haven't managed to find a proof. Note that this inequality can be rewritten as
$$ \sum_{i,j,k}^K \frac{x_k}{\sqrt{x_ix_j}} \geq K^3. $$
Numerically it always seems to clearly hold. Using the fact that the $1/2$-norm is higher than the $1$-norm, I could show that it is higher than $K^2$, but not any $K^3$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me that you might not know about the act of [accepting an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), but I could be wrong. You are of course not forced to accept an answer even if there's ten of them or on the contrary only one, and you don't have to provide any justification for accepting or not accepting answers, it was just a heads up to see if you were aware of that aspect. It helps us know whether the poster of the question felt that an answer truly answered their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by Holder:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^K\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i}}\right)^2\sum_{i=1}^Kx_i\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^K\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i}}\right)^2x_i}\right)^3=K^3.$$

Answer (score 3):

Your sum $S$ also equals
$$\sum_{i,j,k}\frac{x_j}{\sqrt{x_ix_k}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_{i,j,k}\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_jx_k}}.$$
Therefore
$$3S=\sum_{i,j,k}\left(\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_jx_k}}+\frac{x_j}{\sqrt{x_ix_k}}+\frac{x_k}{\sqrt{x_ix_j}}\right)\ge 3K^2$$
on applying AM/GM to each summand.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is equivalent to
$$
\left(\frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^K x_i^{-1/2}\right)^{-2} \le 
\frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^K x_i 
$$
and that is a special case of the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality):
$$
 M_p(x_1, \ldots, x_K) \le M_q (x_1, \ldots, x_K) 
$$
for $p = -\frac 12 < q = 1$.